# When is code platform-dependent?

Tags: c, operating-system, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture

I understand that some algorithm and inline assembly can be platform-dependent. For instance if you write a compiler, will the source code to the compiler be platform-dependent and if I compile your compiler I must use the same version of the source code that corresponds to my architecture?

Comment: You have actually nested two questions in one, while each of these is too broad. The questions I identify: 1) How to know the code I am writing is portable. 2) How to write a compiler which will be cross-platform.

Comment: Pardon the obvious comment. As soon as your code makes assumptions that are not backed by platform-independent standards, you're platform *dependent*. Whether that is to a *specific* platform or a subset of platforms is not really relevant. There are *many* ways one can fall into that pool, frankly too many to list here, but I'm confident some of the answers you'll see will demonstrate some of them. There's a reason standards like POSIX exist, and believe me, depending on the architecture you're coding against, they can vary from trivial to *very* difficult to comply with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it would be platform dependent if you do anything that takes for granted something that can change in the language; including, but not limited to:

- assuming a particular character set (we all assume ascii from time to time)
- assuming the particulars of how floats work, or their structure.
- writing code that assumes some endianness (asside from hton , ntos which work correctly when implemented correctly)
- adding inline assembly to take advantage of some processor feature (sse/mmx etc)
- depending on some external library that isn't a portable vanilla C library

edit:
one of the biggest that I forgot was assuming the sizes of integral types, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`  -  those types are ordered by size, but there is pretty much no guarantee; and the most common arches differ on what a long is etc... so c99 introduced the `int8_t` `int16_t`... etc types.

Comment: Usage of hardware peripherals, registers, interrupts, timing assumptions, memory maps...